# Unwanted scaling when overlaying GraphicsComplex graphic onto image?

Tags: graphics, mesh

I have a collection of complex hull meshes, which I would like to overlay onto an image. These complex hull meshes were obtained from the original image, and I have verified that their mesh coordinates (pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/XtKtjm7q) for reference) are close to the original bounds of the image of size {2752,2192} pixels.

[image: Convex hull meshes]

However, converting their mesh coordinates to a GraphicsComplex graphic seems to resize the output image to {360,282} instead of a larger graphic near the size {2752,2192}.

`ImageDimensions@[Graphics[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[#], {Thick, Red, MeshCells[#, 1]}]] & /@ allCluster]`
`ImageDimensions@pic`

Output: {360, 282}, {2752, 2192}

As a result, overlaying the complex hull meshes over the original image results in a translated/scaled offset that I'm unable to fix.
`Show[pic, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[#], {Thick, Red, MeshCells[#, 1]}]] & /@ allCluster]`

[image: scaled overlay]

This used to work in an older version of Mathematica (12.0.2), but since upgrading to the 12.2 I have been unable to obtain the same overlays that I used to get.
[image: correct overlay with older version of mathematica]

Is there an option to output `Graphics` at its original size instead of rescaling so that I can overlay my images properly? I have tried adding an ImageSize parameter as such, to no avail. I have also tried using ImageResize, but got the same image with the red outlines in a lower resolution.

`Show[pic, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[#], {Thick, Red, MeshCells[#, 1]}], ImageSize -> {2752, 2192}] & /@ allCluster]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure why `Show` scales the meshes, but `HighlightImage` gives me exactly what I want!

`HighlightImage[pic, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[#], {Thick, Red, MeshCells[#, 1]}]] & /@ allCluster]`

[image: correct overlay]